# $C^1[0,1]$ is Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, complete-spaces

> I was trying to solve the following problem:
>
> [image]

**This is what I have tried. Please tell me if my attempt is correct:**

> [image]

Is my above arguments correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your last argument can be simplified. You have $f_n \to f, \,f_n'\to g$ uniformly on $[0,1].$ For any $x\in [0,1]$ we have

$$f_n(x) - f_n(0) = \int_0^x f_n'$$

by the FTC. But the left side $\to f(x) - f(0)$ and the right side $\to \int_0^x g.$ Thus $f\in C^1,$ by the FTC.

Comment: Yes that is a better possibility. Thank you.

Comment: Is my overall argument correct? Please tell me if I went wrong anywhere. Being a beginner in the subject it is important me to know if I have done anything wrong.